# R: comparing with few values

Tags: r, compare

I've got 2 files:

```
eg
V1      V2    V3     V4        V5        V6        V7       V8 V9
1 0.066 0.71125  1.77 0.5045 0.7417104  1.584007  0.872757 1.729945  4
2 0.500 6.07500 20.30 1.7500 9.5017100 17.255490 11.180490 6.388851  4
3 0.670 0.67000  0.67 0.6700 0.0000000  0.670000  0.670000 0.000000  1
```

and

```
kl
 I    II   III    IV     
1  0.80  0.60  0.40  0.20
2  0.75  0.55  0.35  0.15 
3 65.60 50.70 38.80 24.00
```

I'd like to compare all of V2 rows from "eg" with all adequatly rows from "kl", 'cuz I need (as a result) evaluate which row got which class (I, II, III, IV or V for the rest) in next column.
E.g.

```
if eg[1,2] >= kl[1,1] --> I
if eg[1,2] >= kl[2,1] --> II
if eg[1,2] >= kl[3,1] --> III
if eg[1,2] >= kl[4,1] --> IV
else --> V
```

and the same for eg[2,2] and eg[3,2].

I repaired my first loop and an iteration like this, but (of course) it doesn't work...:

```
eg <- read.csv("eg.csv", header=F, sep=";")
eg <- eg[, -c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)]
eg <- t(eg)
as.numeric(as.character(eg))

for (i in eg) {
if (is.na(eg[i,1]) || eg[i,1] == "NA") {
cat(("0"), sep=";")
} else if (eg[i,1] >= kl[i,1]) {
cat(("1"), sep=";")
} else if (eg[i,1] >= kl[i,2]) {
cat(("2"), sep=";")
} else if (eg[i,1] >= kl[i,3]) {
cat(("3"), sep=";")
} else if (eg[i,1] >= kl[i,4]) {
cat(("4"), sep=";") 
} else {
cat(("5"), sep=";")
next}
}
```

R returns good values only for two first line, then it writes:

```
 00Error in if (is.na(eg[i, 1]) || eg[i, 1] == "NA") { : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

But when I make the same for each row separately - it worked. NOW NOT :(

Please, help me! And thank you!

Comment: In your pseudocode all conditions are `>` while in your loop some are `<`. What class is valid when a value from `eg$V2` matches multiple classes from `kl`? Also, in your `for` loop, I guess it should be: `for (i in 1:length(eg[,2])) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much more compact method:

```
c( "I", "II", "III", "IV") [ findInterval(eg[ , 1] , rev(kl[1, ] )) ]
```

This uses the `findInterval` function to determine which category (as a number) each `eg` value is in. (The `findInterval` function requires these to be non-decreasing, so in this problem we need to `rev()`-erse the boundary values. That is then used to select from a character vector.

If you post an example that makes sense (rather than one with a varying number of items per row) we can demonstrate how to put in a loop or an `sapply` call.

Step-by-step, which for R means from the innermost to outermost:

> 1) reverse the ordering of the `kl` vector so that it can be used as the breaks in `findInterval`
>
> 2) The run the `eg[,1]` column through `findInterval(.,.)` returning an index to be used with "["
>
> 3) Extract the appropriate items from the category character vector (based on the break interval that the eg[,1] value fell into.

The code above was posted when there wasn't a proper example. Often it is needed to put `-Inf` and `Inf` on either side of the breakpoints so that you don't get zero indices from `findInterval`. This codes seems to work on the dataframes offered now:

```
apply(kl,1,function(x) c( "V", "I", "II", "III", "IV") [ 
                                findInterval(eg[ , 1] , c( -Inf, rev(x ),Inf) ) ]  )
     1     2     3  
[1,] "V"   "V"   "V"
[2,] "II"  "II"  "V"
[3,] "III" "III" "V"
```

> probably will want to transpose this because of the way the `apply` function returns row processing in column-order.

(I think the problem specification is still messed up, since it refers to a row 4 of a 3 row object (that also has 4 columns. The numeric values only make sense when used as rows.)

Comment: It look very good, however, I want to receive only one column, only for 3 first lines...
I need eg[1,2] to compare with kl[1,]; eg[2,2] to compare with kl[2,] and eg[3,2] to compare with kl[3,]

Comment: Are we talking about the same column? eg[1,2] is 0.71125.  If you just want to do one column, then you should be able to use the findInterval approach to do all of the comparisons except for the newly added NA comparison.

Comment: If it were only a "comparison" with `NA` you could just let findInterval return `NA` for input of `NA` and now that I think of it, "NA" will never be an input from a numeric column anyway. So you don't need that second test in the first conditional.

Comment: I'm not so good in R - I just starting with it, but I suppose I uderstand it, and now I know how can I use in my calculations!
Thank you so much @DWin !